# Getting MVC to ignore route to site root

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm working on a site that is partially static content and partially MVC.  The root of the site is index.html and I have all of the controllers explicitly routed and all html files ignored.  However, when you hit the root of the website, it tries to route it.  How can I tell the route engine to ignore the root of the site? www.mysite.com should not be routed, but instead go to index.html.  Here is my routing configuration:

```
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("*.html|js|css|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "vendor_signup","{vendor}/signup/{action}/",
            new { controller = "Signup", action = "Index", vendor=UrlParameter.Optional}  // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "signup","signup/{action}/",
            new { controller = "Signup", action = "Index", vendor=Vendors.PCICentral}  // Parameter defaults
        );
//more routes below
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the routes was still in {} which made it try to parse the root.

Answer (score 16):

I believe what you mean is when someone accesses `/` on your website, you don't want to use MVC, but show a static page. To achieve this, you need to tell MVC to ignore that route and let webforms handle it. Webforms then should show you `/index.html` when it gets the request `/`.

Simply adding this before your routes should work:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("");
```

Comment: Adding this ignore route didn't work. I get: *HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.*

Comment: @Organic In that case, check your default documents. Either you don't have an index.html or similar, or it's not set up in IIS. In IIS go to your website and have a look at the "Default Document" property. If one of those documents exist, it will show that document, otherwise you'll get this warning.