# Add Static HTML file to Root of Azure MVC App

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4

Where do I add a static html file "mycoolpage.html" to a MVC4 project so it will be served when requesting "mysite.cloudapp.net/mycoolpage.html" when deployed to azure?

I've tried adding it to the project and setting up routes like

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.html");
```

and tried returning it from a controller using the following route

```
  routes.MapRoute(
              "mycoolsite.html",
              "mycoolsite.html",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Coolsite" }
              );
```

Comment: I don't think being on Azure (websites, VMs, or cloud services) will make any difference - this is purely an MVC issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried: `routes.IgnoreRoute("*.html")`, with the file in the root folder of your MVC site?

(From: [Getting MVC to ignore route to site root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150747/getting-mvc-to-ignore-route-to-site-root))